# RuntimeException: Method putExtra in android.content.Intent not mocked

Tags: android, android-intent, junit, mocking, mockito

I am writing Unit Tests for an app module. I somehow have problems with mocking Android calls. What I **don't** want is to use an InstrumentationTest for my test case.

Here are my classes. Beginning with a less important model class:

```
package de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SpecialData implements Serializable {

    int someData_1;
    int someData_2;

    public int getSomeData_1() {
        return someData_1;
    }

    public void setSomeData_1(int someData_1) {
        this.someData_1 = someData_1;
    }

    public int getSomeData_2() {
        return someData_2;
    }

    public void setSomeData_2(int someData_2) {
        this.someData_2 = someData_2;
    }
}
```

Here is my centralized manager for launching Activities:

```
package de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class IntentManager {
    private Context context;

    public IntentManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean goToSpecialActivity(SpecialData specialData) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpecialActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SpecialActivityManager.INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA, specialData);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my "specialized" manager:

package de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SpecialActivityManager {

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final IntentManager intentManager;
    private boolean specialShouldBeShown = true;

    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA = "INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA";

    public SpecialActivityManager(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + ".special", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.intentManager = new IntentManager(context);
    }

    public void showSpecial(SpecialData specialData) {
        if (specialShouldBeShown) {
            intentManager.goToSpecialActivity(specialData);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my unit test:

package de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyBoolean;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class SpecialManagerTest {

    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private SpecialActivityManager specialActivityManager;
    private Intent intent;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        context = mock(Context.class);
        intent = mock(Intent.class);
        sharedPreferences = mock(SharedPreferences.class);
        editor = mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class);

        when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPreferences);
        when(sharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(editor);
        when(editor.putBoolean(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(editor);

        specialActivityManager = new SpecialActivityManager(context);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowSpeciall() throws Exception {
        SpecialData specialData = mock(SpecialData.class);
        IntentManager intentManager = mock(IntentManager.class);

        when(intentManager.goToSpecialActivity(specialData)).thenReturn(true);

        specialActivityManager.showSpecial(specialData);

        verify(intent).putExtra(SpecialActivityManager.INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA, specialData);
        verify(context).startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putExtra in android.content.Intent not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

        at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java)
        at de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample.IntentManager.goToSpecialActivity(IntentManager.java:18)
        at de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample.SpecialActivityManager.showSpecial(SpecialActivityManager.java:23)
        at de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample.SpecialManagerTest.testShowSpeciall(SpecialManagerTest.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I already tried to follow [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-) link. But then I could not verify my method calls:

```
verify(intent).putExtra(SpecialActivityManager.INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA, specialData);
verify(context).startActivity(intent);
```

So is it possible to somehow mock the `putExtra()` method or do you have any other solution for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SpecialManagerTest` you just need to test that `intentManager.goToSpecialActivity(specialData)` is called.

If the new activity is started is a responsibility of `IntentManager` and it should be tested there.

First to make `SpecialManager` testable you need to pass its attributes as parameters (in that way you can mock them):

```
public class SpecialActivityManager {

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final IntentManager intentManager;
    private boolean specialShouldBeShown = true;

    public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA = "INTENT_EXTRA_SPECIAL_DATA";

    public SpecialActivityManager(Context context, IntentManager intentManager) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + ".special", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.intentManager = intentManager;
    }

    public void showSpecial(SpecialData specialData) {
        if (specialShouldBeShown) {
            intentManager.goToSpecialActivity(specialData);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your test should be:

```
public class SpecialActivityManagerTest {

    private IntentManager intentManager;
    private SpecialActivityManager specialActivityManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Context context = mock(Context.class);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mock(SharedPreferences.class);
        intentManager = mock(IntentManager.class);

        when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPreferences);

        specialActivityManager = new SpecialActivityManager(context, intentManager);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowSpeciall() throws Exception {
        SpecialData specialData = mock(SpecialData.class);

        specialActivityManager.showSpecial(specialData);
        verify(intentManager).goToSpecialActivity(specialData);
    }
}
```

Comment: This guy really knows!