# Creating intent in test: "Method putExtra in android.content.Intent not mocked"

Tags: android, android-intent, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to unit test a broadcast receiver which listens for "com.android.music.metachanged" intents using JUnit4 and Mockito.

The broadcast receiver starts a service when it receives an intent. I want to assert that the service is started. I also want to assert that the string extra "artist" of the received intent is the same as the one of the sent intent.

This is what I have so far...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MusicBroadcastReceiverUnitTest {
    private MusicBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Mock
    private Context mContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mReceiver = new MusicBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartMusicRegistrationService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.metachanged");
        intent.putExtra("artist", "SampleArtist");

        mReceiver.onReceive(mContext, intent);
        assertNull(mReceiver.getResultData());

        ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
        verify(mContext, times(1)).startService(argument.capture());

        Intent receivedIntent = argument.getValue();
        assertEquals("SampleArtist", receivedIntent.getStringExtra("artist"));
    }
}
```

But this fires a java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putExtra in android.content.Intent not mocked.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617398/runtimeexception-method-putextra-in-android-content-intent-not-mocked) out, but I think the OP had a different problem, since they don't send out an intent from inside the test body.

Comment: Though it's not about ContentValues, this is a dupe of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36555136/1426891

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, I took a look at [Method of ContentValues is not mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555136/method-of-contentvalues-is-not-mocked) as suggested by @Jeff Bowman. Sadly, that question doesn't provide any code, so I hope this will be useful for somebody...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MusicBroadcastReceiverUnitTest {
    private MusicBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Mock
    private Context mContext;

    @Mock
    private Intent androidIntent;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mReceiver = new MusicBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartMusicRegistrationService() {
        try {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Intent.class)
               .withArguments(String.class).thenReturn(androidIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        when(androidIntent.getAction())
          .thenReturn("com.android.music.metachanged");
        when(androidIntent.getStringExtra("artist"))
          .thenReturn("SampleArtist");

        mReceiver.onReceive(mContext, intent);

        ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
        verify(mContext, times(1)).startService(argument.capture());

        Intent receivedIntent = argument.getValue();
        assertEquals("SampleArtist", receivedIntent.getStringExtra("artist"));
    }
}
```

So yeah, I rather mocked "getStringExtra" than "putExtra". But it worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you're like me and saw this error when running unit tests, but you didn't care about testing the `putExtra` portion of the code, you can use:

```
android {
    // ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

in your app's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: this is very interesting, it would be very kind if you add some explanation, that how it achieve that. It worked BTW.